# How to use ajax with autocomplete in jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the following `jquery` with `ajax` call? My `webservice` returns `dataset`.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#ctl00_ContentMain_ddlRegions').change(function(){
        region = $(this).val();
        alert(region);
    });       
});

$('input[type="text"]').autocomplete({               
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "~/EmailActivation/EmailActivation.asmx/GetIsoFromRegion",
            data: "{'option':'" + region + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data,status){
                alert("success");    
            }
        });
        minLength: 4 });
});
```

Right now there is an error in my code so, I cannot even display alert to show region. Error is generated from `autocomplete` section.
When I remove autocomplete section, script works.

What do I need to change and how can I make my `autocomplete` work with the data coming from `webservice`?

Thank you

Comment: You will need to identify where your autocomplete fails. It could be before sending the request, when processing it server-side or even when processing the responses client-side. The "network" tab of your browser's developer tools would probably be of great help.

Comment: The thing is, when I remove my code from autocomplete, I get an alert. As soon as I even type alert("data") in my autocomplete, nothing happens. So, I'm not sure why autocomplete causing the error on a page